# Aiogram CallbackData Too Many arguments and Where i try set callback query handler and set filter for callback i get error

Tags: python-3.x, bots, telegram, aiogram

there!

In officical documentation aiogram write about CallbackData builder as i write
but this not working

When i pass to Inline Keyboard Button Callback data i get error
Too many arguments were passed!
When i try set callback query handler with filter i get errorValueError: Invalid field name 'action'

`

```
`from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.utils.callback_data import CallbackData
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
import config

bot = Bot(token=config.TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot=bot, storage=storage)


class Form(StatesGroup):
    recipient_id = State()
    message = State()


cb_data = CallbackData('action', 'sender_id')


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_cmd(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.get_args():
        if message.chat.id == int(message.get_args()):
            return await message.reply(
                text=f"Упс... не думаю, що писати самому собі гарна ідея. \nРозмісти це посилання у себе в Instagram або Telegram нехай тобі пишуть інші. \n\nОсь твоє посилання: \nhttps://t.me/incognito_valentinka_bot/?start={message.chat.id}")
        else:
            await Form.message.set()
            async with state.proxy() as data:
                data['recipient_id'] = message.get_args()

            return await message.answer(
                text="Напиши повідомлення для людини яка розмістила це посилання. \nНапиши все, що думаєшь. \n\n  Ти можешь відправити текст, фото, відео або голосове повідомлення.")

    await message.answer(
        text=f"Привіт! Щоб почати отримувати валентинки розмісти посилання у себе в профілі інстаграм \n\n Ось твоє посилання:  \nhttps://t.me/incognito_valentinka_bot/?start={message.chat.id}")


@dp.callback_query_handler(cb_data.filter(action='reply'))
async def message_reply(query: types.CallbackQuery, callback_data: dict, state: FSMContext):
    print("hello")
    await Form.message.set()
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['recipient_id'] = callback_data['sender_id']

    await query.answer(text="Напиши відповідь")


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.message)
async def get_message(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['message'] = message.text

        await bot.send_message(
            chat_id=data['recipient_id'],
            text="<b>Нове повідомлення</b>",
            parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML
        )
        # cb = MyCallback(action="reply", sender_id=message.chat.id)
        # cb =callback_msg.new(action="reply", sender_id=message.chat.id)
        inline_keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        inline_keyboard.row(
            types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                text="Відповісти",
                callback_data=cb_data.new(action='reply', sender_id=message.chat.id)
            )
        )
        await bot.send_message(
            chat_id=data['recipient_id'],
            text=data['message'],
            reply_markup=inline_keyboard
        )

    await message.answer(
        text='<b>Повідомлення доставлено.</b>',
        parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML
    )


async def set_my_commands():
    commands = [
        types.BotCommand(command='/start', description='Отримай своє посилання!')
    ]
    await bot.set_my_commands(commands=commands)


async def on_startup(dp):
    print('Starting...')
    await set_my_commands()
    print('Running...')


async def on_shutdown(dp):
    print('Shutting down...')
    print('Stopped!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(
        dispatcher=dp,
        skip_updates=True,
        on_startup=on_startup,
        on_shutdown=on_shutdown,
    )`
```

I try change aiogram version
I install latest python version before i use 3.8 upgrade to 3.9 it's not solved my problem
I try to change name of argument but this is not working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
 inline_keyboard.row(
            types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                text="Відповісти",
                callback_data=cb_data.new(action='reply', sender_id=message.chat.id)
            )
        )
```

Try .pack () `cb_data.new(action='reply', sender_id=message.chat.id).pack()`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).